# TypeError: Object is not a function or its return value is not iterable, when i use useState (function component)

Tags: reactjs, use-state, function-composition

> ```
>   const [text, setText] = useSate('')
>    const [day, setDay] = useSate('')
>   const [remainder, setRemainder] = useSate(false)
> ```

```
<div className="mb-3">
        <label htmlFor="task" className="form-label">Task</label>
        <input type="text" className="form-control" id="task"
          onChange={(e) => {
            setText(e.target.text)
          }}
        />
```

Error:
I what to set useState for input on function component, on event to fill the setText..., and than pass that data in app.js fali and fill that in useState, then that will render componet with new data, but a get error

**TypeError: Object is not a function or its return value is not iterable**

That error appear when i write the:

> const [text, setText] = useSate('')
> const [day, setDay] =
> useSate('')
> const [remainder, setRemainder] = useSate(false)

Comment: We might tend to overlook small details. consider having a linter to employ good coding practices and identify errors easily.

Answer (score 4):

It is not `useSate` but `useState`, you are missing `t` letter there.